# PhpStorm setting to change color of collapse guide blocks in gutter

Tags: phpstorm

Does anyone know how to change the color, in PhpStorm 2016.3, for the tan bars within the gutter?  It's quite distracting on a darker theme.

[image]

Comment: What are those colors in first place? It  looks like VCS status (modified/added lines) to me or something like that. But generally speaking -- `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts` -- and start going trough all styles if you do not know which one this might be.

Comment: I didn't notice that at first, but I think you're right, it's the VCS status indicator.  I'm aware of where to change the colors, just had no idea what I was looking for there.  This gives me a start - thanks.